# No proper answer to bounty

Tags: discussion

Regarding Stack Overflow question *[Laravel Mix: Update a Node.js dependency](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42068686/laravel-mix-update-a-node-dependency)*, I wanted an answer that explained how to get [Homebrew](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homebrew_(package_management_software)) or other to properly install Node.js, [Vue.js](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vue.js), etc. on OS X.

Neither of the answers give a satisfactory answer and are not accepted by the OP either.

I now have to award the bounty to one of them, but I do not agree they are awardable. What should I do? It's not the points, but I am no wiser than when I set the bounty.

Comment: Here is a (quite dastardly) idea. Add an answer. Award the bounty. Delete answer. Problem solved. ...Well, this one is.

Comment: @usr2564301 nah - won't do that

Comment: @usr2564301 How and why would it even be possible to award a bounty to yourself?

Comment: If you can answer a question you can get a bounty, no?

Comment: Not on your own question. From https://stackoverflow.com/help/bounty: "(You cannot award a bounty to your own answer.)"

Comment: If the system allowed that then everyone would do it to avoid losing the rep from the bounty even if they got an answer they liked.

Comment: Anyway not my question

Comment: It's still your bounty. At this point you could: post another bounty and/or try to actively promote the question on social media to get more attention on it but you may have to ask elsewhere or open a bug.

Comment: According to https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16065/how-does-the-bounty-system-work (search: "Unanswered") it is not required to award a bounty.  The oldest or highest voted answer will receive half-credit.  The bounty at least drew additional attention to your question, though it is frustrating to have learned nothing as a result!

Comment: @Daniel: but that's mplungjan's problem: not one of the answers are considered worthy of it, not even half. The auto-award will kick in, and I am all out of dastardly ideas. (I may have been confused with "self-answered" bountied questions above, which do *not* receive the bounty – but then nobody else would too.)

Comment: Are the answers wrong? not useful? unclear? there's a tool for dealing with such answers. Two in fact.

Comment: we can help you downvoting the answer :p so the automatic bounty won't go to any answer :p

Comment: Only one of those answers is eligible for the bounty.

Comment: I've had this problem before and the system eventually auto awarded half the bounty. Apart from DVing an answer so it doesn't meet the auto criteria there isn't much you can do.

Comment: Yeah, I'm not a big fan of the auto-bounty...

Comment: @KevinB - which tools, a few hours before auto awarding? Neither are complete useful answers in my opinion

Comment: Voting, and leaving comments. That's all you've got

Comment: I'd like to imagine that if a comment was left on that answer much earlier on in the process stating that it doesn't answer the question it wouldn't have received so many upvotes. but then again, people upvote such answers all the time

Comment: Now both answers have been downvoted into negativety, can we tag this `status-completed`? (A possibly irrelevant obsv.: both +4's remain, meaning most likely that none was taken back.)